# WordPressで店舗検索を機能させる方法は何ですか？

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

私はWordPressを使用して企業サイトを構築しています。
[foodpanda.co.jp](https://foodpanda.co.jp)のような店舗検索機能を作りたいです。
プラグインを検索しましたが、その方法が見つかりませんでした。
それを行う方法を知っている人はいますか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: プラグインは有料でもいいですか？

Comment: はい、プラグインが有料でも大丈夫です。

Comment: しかし、無料でできれば幸いです。

Comment: テーマのカテゴリーテンプレートを作成して作るのが良いかともいます。https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88

Answer (score 0):

かなり高機能でMapもついてきてしまいますが、
https://superstorefinder.net/
があります。

https://superstorefinder.net/superstorefinderwp/addon/custommarker/info-window-icons/
これらを用いてマップは最悪ミニマムで表現できればある程度はできる気がします。

アドバイスですが、〇〇のようなサイトを作りたいといわれたときは要注意です。
〇〇のようなUIなのか〇〇のような機能なのかこの辺りは非常にあいまいになりがちです。
また仮に店舗機能といっても店舗を検索する機能や店舗をカテゴライズする機能とさらに細かく分岐されていきます。
また検索する機能といっても、郵便番号で検索する機能なのか？フリーテキストで検索する機能なのか？さらにさらに要件を細かく細かく詰めていく必要があります。

〇〇のようなサイトを作りたいと顧客に言われたとしても、要件としては〇〇のようなではなくて、「郵便番号を用いた店舗検索機能」とか「地域別にカテゴライズされ、表現できるCMS機能」とかきちんと要件を決めていきましょう。このあたりの話は「要件定義」と「基本設計」という言葉で表現されており、様々な書籍や記事で言及されておりますので参考にしてみてください。

Comment: uiと機能はすべてfoodpandaと同じでなければなりません。

Comment: そうなるとfoodpandaがWPのプラグインを利用していない限り全く同じものは難しいでしょう。みた限りWPではなさそうですが。